# Views not showing some content

Tags: views

I have the following code in the footer to a view:

```
<script src="https://mysite/sites/all/libraries/js/listnav/jquery-tablenav.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
(function ($) {
    $("document").ready(function() {
   $("table").attr("id","myTable");
   $('#myTable').tablenav();
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

tablenav(), incidentally, is a simple rewrite of esteinborn's excellent listnav.  This works just fine.  Below is an image of part of the Views Preview, and in the Preview the navigation tool works just fine.

[image]

The problem is that the navigation tool does not show up in the view itself.  Inspection of the HTML shows that this is not just a case of visibility: the content that is available in Views Preview is simply not in the View itself. Stats:

Drupal: 7.64
Views: 7.x-3.21
jQuery 1.10.2

Comment: Why not add the js properly to your theme? The Views Preview is most likely using the admin theme, while on the "front-end" it's your default theme, so that is the difference. Does it work with Bartik? BTW did you know you can achieve something similar with the Summary and Glossary options of Contextual filters in Views?

Comment: Ten thousand thanks for this.  Yes, Bartik works, as do almost all other themes.  It was only the Marinelli theme that I use as the default that doesn't handle the addition of the navigator tool.  Again, thank you very much.